# How to take screenshot without using keyboard? (problem with Java and VMWare)

Tags: java, keyboard, screen-scraping, screenshot, vmware

I'm facing a little problem.

1. I have a virtual OS in VMWare and i need to take a screenshot of it.
2. I have to be able to take screenshot from original OS(my software is running in original OS and key presses in virtual OS are forbidden :)).
3. If i operate in virtual OS the keyboard and mouse is used by VMWare and original OS cannot take screenshot using key combination "Alt+Print Screen".

What i have to be able to do is:

1. I have to be able to operate in virtual OS(i will be using it while software is taking screenshots) and software in original OS has to be able to take screenshot of all the windows in original OS(including VMWare window)
2. **There shouldn't be any key presses in virtual OS**

My view of solving this problem is to take a screenshot in original OS without pressing keyboard shortcut "Alt+Print Screen" (because keyboard is used by virtual OS). So how could taking a screenshot be achieved without using keyboard?

Can anyone give me an idea how to managa that (in some programming language for example:c or c++?) **My software is written in Java** so it's possible to run c and c++ code from there.

All the best to you all,
KMI

Comment: Hmm why dont you look around? I never used VMWARE player specifically but it should have options that lets the virtual OS capture/release hardware, USB drives, mouse pointers and in your case, the keyboard. VirtualBox has a toolbar superimposed over the guest OS that lets you capture/release hardware and surprise!, take shots!

Comment: are you talking about screenshot(s) from VMware console ???

Comment: No, my Java program needed to take screenshot from original OS (from Java directly). The answer is in the  "createScreenCapture" method in Robot class like "aioobe" mentioned!:)

Comment: Oh, and aitchnyu, I definitely need to use keyboard and mouse in virtual OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ***So how could taking a screenshot be achieved without using keyboard?***

You should have a look at the [`Robot`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) class. Specifically, the [`createScreenCapture`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html#createScreenCapture%28java.awt.Rectangle%29) method.

Comment: Oooh, how did i miss that (my current method was using also robot to take screenshot using key presses but i didn't see that method). That solved my problem, now the VMWare window is captured nicely! Thank you!

Comment: then s/he will be lots of problem with black `Image` without using http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/13/screen-image/ +1